# Logstash multiline codec for Celery stacktraces

Tags: python, celery, logstash

Trying to create a configuration for logstash that correctly parses Celery's log format, including multiline stacktraces. An example of logging output might look like this:

```
[2014-04-15 15:11:27,350: DEBUG/Worker-4] Doing some work.
[2014-04-15 15:11:27,362: ERROR/MainProcess] Task core.tasks.sometask[92dc34bd-8139-4f98-b359-d78caf68381d] raised unexpected: ValueError('Foobar',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./venvs/backend-33/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 238, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./venvs/backend-33/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 416, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "util.py", line 151, in wrapper
    rv = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "tasks.py", line 104, in do_something_useful
    raise ValueError('Foobar')
ValueError: Foobar
```

At some point I got Grok ready to parse the single line output, but the multiline is a problem. This configuration:

```
input {
    stdin {
        codec => multiline {
            'negate' => true
            'pattern' => '^\['
            'what' => 'previous'
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Is taken more or less straight from the Logstash documentation for the multiline codec, when I run it, it produces no output at all.

I tried using a multiline filter instead, but it yielded the same result, I also tried running logstash with --verbose but it didn't give any useful information. What's going on here?

Comment: With your logs and configuration, it is worked on me with logstsash-1.3.3.

Comment: I only tried it with logstash-1.4.0, with the file input it works like a charm.

Comment: The multine filter should be forgotten, it is strictly the same as the codec but is not multi-threadable (ie: very bad performance)

Answer (score 3):

After some more Googling I found the answer, apparently the multiline codec doesn't play nice with the stdin input. Using the file input, and now it works.

See: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1629